# phonegap build is not working

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build

I'm doing my first phonegap project: i have started from a hello world template, did an ajax connection to an external json feed and display the data. Everything works fine when i test on  desktop browser or on phone using the phonegap mobile app.

After that i created a zip file with all the files, i upload it to build.phonegap.com and install the apk version. However after i install the apk (with debug and hydration) the app show just the phonegap logo and the blinking "connection to device" and that's it. Strange is that i don't have those elements anymore.

I check for times that i uploaded the right archive. Checked on different devices and even with other test apps. Same thing - the phonegap logo and blinking message (checked 100 times and i don't have these in the code)

Also i noticed that on phonegap build it says no plugins but i installed at least 3 : phonegap-push,network and camera.

Please tell me what i'm doing wrong.

Comment: The solution was to remove cordova.js from html source file and have config.xml in the same place like index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to remove cordova.js from html source file and have config.xml in the same place like index.html

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried building an app without the external json? Try that first. Connecting to external resources had issues in of itself.

Look up white listing for PhoneGap.